# How To Get First Word In The String

Tags: javascript, regex

Answers on the web relates to other programming languages. I have done many searches but none seems to work. I'm looking for per title.

```
var str = ["bob, b", "the, d", "builder, e", "can", "he", "fix", "it" ]
str.match(/^(\w+)/) // Uncaught TypeError: str.match is not a function
```

I have tried to look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) but....I'm still learning and my not be using it correctly.

How do I return only `bob` and not `bob, b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nc56rpuj/1/)

```
var str = ["bob, b", "the, d", "builder, e", "can", "he", "fix", "it" ];
for(var i=0; i < str.length; ++i){
    console.log(str[i].match('[a-zA-Z]+'));
}
```

Comment: `str.match('[a-zA-Z]+')` is what I'm after. Thanks all.

Comment: @Sylar, Yup sorry I misspelled the regex, this why I removed it because my laptop almost died before I could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You're running `match()` not on the string, but on an array of strings. `str` is an array (and thus has no idea what's inside it), but `str[0]`, the first element of that array, is a `String` and has a `match()` method. Run the Regex on `str[0]` and you should get back "bob".

And it would be good to rename your array variable to reflect this (e.g. `strArray`).

Comment: OP >> "*How do I return only `bob` and not `bob, b`?*"

Comment: No. `str[2]` returns the letter `b`. `str[0]` returns `[`

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Why you removed your answer? It worked you know.

Answer (score 0):

About your regex :

First you have to look at the beginning of the string with **^**.

Then you want to match letters (or number ?) as long as there isn't any other char :

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Your regex should be something like

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

And as @Compynerd255 said : you need to apply your match() function on your strings and not your array.

Comment: You can't do regex on arrays.

Comment: @penne12 quite sure it's exactly what I just said

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function getFirstWord(str) {
  var matched = str.match(/^\w+/);
  if(matched) {
    return matched[0];
  }

  console.error("No Word found");
  return -1;
};

var str = ["bob, b", "the, d", "builder, e", "can", "he", "fix", "it"];

for(var i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i += 1) {
  var item = str[i];
  var firstWord = getFirstWord(item);

  console.log(firstWord);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey first you need to get the 0th element from the `array` and then `split` it with coma so that it will return you an `array`, once you get the `array` you can extract the first element out of it.

In a nut shell the following works

```
var str = ["bob, b", "the, d", "builder, e", "can", "he", "fix", "it" ]

console.log(str[0].split(',')[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't apply regex on an array. Iterate over each element:

```
/(\w+)/.exec(str[i])[1]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxgo6oyp/)